# How to add a different class to the same class in JQuery?

Tags: jquery-selectors, addclass

I have no code to start off with, because I'm not advanced in JQuery and this seems like advanced stuff here. I know how to add classes, hide elements and other sorts of things but this is a new thing for me here. Here's the problem. I have content being served via php and mysql. The content will all share the same class and will be listed five per page. I need to have each of the same classes to have an extra class added to them to give it a unique class. An example of what the html looks like is below.

```
  <div id="1" class="example"></div>
  <div id="2" class="example"></div>
  <div id="3" class="example"></div>
  <div id="4" class="example"></div>
  <div id="5" class="example"></div>
```

I need Jquery to do this to the html:

```
  <div id="1" class="example ex1"></div>
  <div id="2" class="example ex2"></div>
  <div id="3" class="example ex3"></div>
  <div id="4" class="example ex4"></div>
  <div id="5" class="example ex5"></div>
```

It will not be practical to create scripts for the Id tag, because if I have a thousand Id's, then I will have to replicate  the script a thousand times per id and more so as the list gets longer. This is only for javascript purposes so I want to keep it within javascript. If there is a way to accomplish this on the server side as well I'll take those suggestions as well. Thanks to all in advance for any help with this problem.

Comment: but why do you need an extra class when it already has an id? I mean with the classes its even more worse? the ids can just be 1 item I also used the ids but there were 3000 items and otherwise you can always use a custom attribute (not recommend)

Comment: You obviously don't know much about server side/ database content and the unque id's. It's not practical to have a script replicated for a thousand Id's if you get my drift.I say this with no disrespect.

Comment: Yes I do, but no I dont get your drift, because adding a class with the id is overkill, and classes are much slower then Id's, so can you explain yourself more?

Comment: Clearly I stated that only five will be listed at a time. The following page will be id=6, id=7,id=8, and so on. That's why I said it will not be practical to make a script for each id. This is a list that will grow on a day to day basis. The class is for CSS styling, because yet again, it will not be practical to style for the many id's when you can style them all with one class name. The added class is for javascript and nothing more (meaning no style changes).

Comment: so when id=6 it also needs class ex1?

Comment: see my answer :) I hope you understand it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I finnaly understand what you want

this code is needed

```
// Wait on the document to be loaded
$(function(){
    // get every element with the class example in an array and loop
    // through it(each) with i  as index
    $(".example").each(function(i){
        // add class ex with the index
        // this is the element we are pointing at so a div
        $(this).addClass("ex" + i);
    });
});​
```

but you could do this easily on server side when you loop through your array with 5 divs ;)

Comment: I just tried this and it is not adding the class. I'm not sure as to why, but no errors neither.

Comment: @Tony did you include jQuery?

Comment: Even in jsfiddle the class stays the same. I'm also testing all this out on my local server. My other javascripts are working perfectly fine, so I know I'm linked to my jquery file. Not sure what's happening here. I do appreiciate the help though.

Answer (score 2):

If I read your comments correctly, you have 5 items per page and the class will be ex1 ex2 ... ex5 respectively.

If so, here is the script:

```
var itemsPerPage = 5;
$(".example").each(function(){       
    var number = this.id % itemsPerPage;
    if (number == 0) number = itemsPerPage;
    $(this).addClass("ex"+ number);
});
```

Or short version:

```
var itemsPerPage = 5;
$('.example').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('ex'+ ((this.id % itemsPerPage) == 0 ? itemsPerPage : (this.id % itemsPerPage));
});
```

Or shortest version is EaterOfCorpses's answer if you don't care about the ID at all. Each method has its own pros and cons.

**Example 1: Wrong ID order**

```
<div id="6" class="example">
<div id="8" class="example">
<div id="7" class="example">
```

EaterOfCorpses's will generate

```
<div id="6" class="example ex0">
<div id="8" class="example ex1">
<div id="7" class="example ex2">
```

My script will generate

```
<div id="6" class="example ex1">
<div id="8" class="example ex3">
<div id="7" class="example ex2">
```

**Example 2: random ID (EaterOfCorpses's pros)**

```
<div id="15blahblah" class="example">
<div id="5" class="example">
<div id="10" class="example">
```

EaterOfCorpses's will generate

```
<div id="15blahblah" class="example ex0">
<div id="5" class="example ex1">
<div id="10" class="example ex2">
```

My script will generate same class and error at 15blahblah, which may be both good (to detect error in IDs) and bad (JS does not run for that particular record)

```
<div id="15blahlbah" class="example exNil">  
<div id="5" class="example ex5">
<div id="10" class="example ex5">
```

Cool.

Comment: your script seems to make my javascript error out. I'm trying it both ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.each($(".example"), function(){
        $(this).addClass("x" + this.id);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Actually in my JQuery lookups today (on their site), I had a feeling that .each will play an important role with what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll try your script to see how this works out and will be back to update/comment my results.

Comment: I just realized that I'm not 100% sure what your script is doing exactly so that I can apply it to my setup properly. It would be of great help and educational for me and all who may ever come across this same sitaution. Thanks in advance though.

Comment: I will, only as soon as I know exactly what's going on in the script and am able to apply it without guessing around with it.

Comment: I just tried this as well and it also is not adding the class, yet no error. In other words .eample stays as .example instead of the ".example ex1"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G4QJC/ i put everything on that fiddle just check, if you still cant accept then there is a problem with your code

Comment: This what I get from the jsfiddel - <div id="1" class="example">1</div>   <div id="2" class="example">2</div>   <div id="3" class="example">3</div>   <div id="4" class="example">4</div>   <div id="5" class="example">5</div>. No Added class.

Comment: I removed all my scripts and just ran all these by their self and still no added class. Plus I would love to give you guys an upvote but I'm new and need to build my reputation in order to upvote. You guys definitely deserve it for the efforts, so I hope you guys can be happy with my sincere thank yous.

Comment: @Tony you know that you only can see the result in the result frame and check it with firebug or webkit inspector? I tried in the jsfiddler to add colors to make it visually visible

Comment: I see that it somehow works but it does not show up in the html markup, in which I was looking at. Now I'm going to give this a shot in my work environment. I'll be sure to run them all and give you guys all some much respspect. I was expecting it show up in the html markup as does the .attr when applied.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses It does show up in webkit inspector, but not when I right click to view source and thats why I didn't see it before. I'll actually be using the added class for js purposes (not css) and havent tried it yet. I do have hopes that it will work the way I want it though. Thanks again for sure.

Comment: @Tony source is the data you get from the request so the javascript is not yet executed :)

Comment: @Sandra Sekhar Walajapet - your code as well works but I already gave the right answer to EaterOfCorpses, and you answered first but he was more detailed as to what was going on in the script, plus he allowed me to see with a visualization using css in jsfiddle and explaining why I couldn't see it in the source code and the proper way to view the source code to see that it was actually being applied. Thank you both very much for this has been a good learning experience, either way.

Comment: Whatever just learnt a new thing not to answer on low rep guys

Comment: I just signed up a couple of days ago and you shouldn't whine about not being able to be upvoted because this is a place of helping and learning as well. Others will be able to come here and learn from both of you because I explained that both of you gave the right answer. Others can come and upvote your answer can't they? With your attitude they may not feel like doing so, since it means so much. I'll say it again that I do appreciate your promptness and speed with the answer you gave. I really mean that and hope that you can appreciate as well. Thank you Sandra.

Comment: @Chandra - I just fully tested yours and it actually doesn't do what I needed because all it did was add the same class to all the divs which was not what I wanted. They all had to have a different class making it unique. So the correct answer was and remains, was the answer EaterOFCorpses gave. I just thought that I will note that so that others aren't confused by my comments saying that yours worked also. Anyways again I do thank you for your efforts though.