# JQuery . after not working on class added via JQuery

Tags: jquery

This question is in relation to a question I posted yesterday. The link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636348/how-to-add-a-different-class-to-the-same-class-in-jquery . The question and problem now is that I will like to have a div added after the div with the class being added. The problem is the script that I'm using adds the div only to an existing/default class name and not the added class via JQuery. The script is below.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){$('.example').each(function(i){$(this).addClass("ex" + i);});

 $('.ex0').after(function(){return'<div class="afterdiv"><a class="afterdiva1" href="#" title="Text."></a><a class="afterdiva2" href="#" title="Text."></a></div>'});
```

The default output is:

```
      <div class="example"></div>
```

The final html output should read as:

```
      <div class="example ex0"></div>
      <div class="afterdiv">
      <a class="afterdiva1"></a>
      <a class="afterdiva2"></a>
      </div>
```

Update- I apologize for not clarifying that each div needs to be unique to/per class. Sincere apologies (I'm new to asking for help here or anywhere else for that matter).

Comment: Hey, it's not super nice to change your question when you already have answers. Start another question if needed, but please, do some work on your own too.

Comment: @Simon Bourdis - Question updated with more clarity. Again I apologize and only took the right answer off but did not take away the upvote. If it was a problem maybe you should report it or something. In other words they obviously leave us the option to remove the answer. Again sorry though.

Comment: @Simon Bourdis I do my own work and common sense would tell you this is only a portion of the overall script and the effect that I'm trying to create here. You should be more kind and not assume that I'm here for the complete code to my script, if so the whole script would be posted. I just need help with only these few issues new to me.

Comment: Then I'd probably go on using an array (or object) to store the class name. But this solution seems pretty trivial, maybe you'd need to show a more concrete example if this don't resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put all these calls into the `.ready()` function. Right now, the second line is executed before the DOM ready callback (because `.ready()` is an asynchrone function).

Comment: I did finally get it to work. Putting and wrapping it all in the .ready was key to all this from the get go. I've been working furiously on this final script and had some mistakes done which were throwing me off, because no error was showing just incomplete functions.Thanks and many apologies for removing my official and correct answer. Plus 10 in thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you execute the code all in the .each() function?  Like this:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
$('.example').each(
function(i){
$(this).addClass("ex" + i).after('<div class="afterdiv"><a class="afterdiva1" href="#" title="Text."></a><a class="afterdiva2" href="#" title="Text."></a></div>');
});
});
```

Comment: I definitely did do this now. I do however have a problem with the classes within the a tags not working. As they are related to the script as well. I do have it being called before and within the .ready() function. Yet they no longer work. They are being displayed but their function is no longer working.

Comment: -You deserve a plus ten. I'm new and limited  to give votes but everything is working as magic. Thanks alot to you and all else who helped. I always appreciate the help and learning experience.

Comment: This does work but the problem I'm now having as that each special class is to have different a tag classes and not be the same. The .after div can be the same but not the a class within the div.

Answer (score 1):

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/tL39C/)

The problem being the .insert was not being included inside DOM ready event

Enclose it inside it and should work fine..

It is working here.. Give some background-Colors to you class names an double check.

Comment: Heum, `.each` function is synchrone: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.each

Comment: @sushanth reddy - Well do you have any suggestions as to how else to go about it?